# How to instruct one router to use another router's internet connection?

Tags: networking, routing

I have two routers:

**Router 1**: Wireless USB - `192.168.8.1` (has internet connection through 4G)

**Router 2**: [Wireless Netgear R6120](https://www.netgear.com/home/wifi/routers/r6120) - `192.168.1.1` (does not have internet connection).

How do I tell Router 2 to use Router 1's internet connection, so that all devices that are connected to Router 2 also have internet?

Comment: You can't, they're not connected to each other.

Comment: The Netgear R6120 allows for VLAN/bridge mode and also can act as wireless access point. I thought of static routes too?

Comment: If I put in the same subnet, e.g. 192.168.8.1 and 192.168.8.2 could that work somehow?

Comment: Are these physically connected somehow? Is one of these routers connected to the other one?

Comment: No, unfortunately not connected to each other physically.

Comment: Then as I said, it's not possible. They're not connected, therefore one can't route packets to/from the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately as gronostaj said it seems you cannot.
See [this post](https://community.netgear.com/t5/General-WiFi-Routers-Non/How-to-use-Netgear-AC1200-R6120-Router-as-Repeater-without/td-p/1624215) on the netgear community.

> You want to put the router into "wireless repeater" mode.
> Only some routers allow this. The thing to look for in the manual is WDS. It is short for Wireless Distribution System.
> Unfortunately, the R6120 is one of the few in the whole R6XXX series that lacks that feature.

It can happen a firmware upgrade... but do not hope so much on that.